# QueryDocumentDelete in Xpages

Tags: xpages

The QueryDocumentDelete in Database script only seems to run from the Notes UI client when a document is deleted.  Is there a similar event when a document is deleted with the Delete Selected Documents simple action?

Comment: What you want to run on that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, QueryDocumentDelete in database script is a Notes UI function and runs only from the Notes client.

Unfortunately, there is no similar event in simple action `Delete Selected Documents`.

An easy workaround is to write the whole functionality of "Delete Selected Documents" on your own. This way you can do things you want to before documents get actually deleted or prevent certain documents from deletion.

Here is a sample code for a button "Delete Selected Documents" which deletes documents in a view panel (with id "viewPanel1"):

```xml
<xp:button
    value="Delete Selected Documents"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        if(!XSP.isViewPanelRowSelected("#{id:viewPanel1}", "_colcbox")){
            XSP.alert("Please select one or more documents to delete.");
            return false;
        }
        if (!XSP.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected documents?')){
             return false;
        }]]></xp:this.script>
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
        var selectedIds = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
        for(i=0; i < selectedIds.length; i++) {
            var docId = selectedIds[i];
            var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docId);
            // do things here you would do on QueryDocumentDelete
            doc.remove(true);
            doc.recycle();
        }}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: Thanks.   I sort of figured I would have to do this but hoping there was an easier way. :)

Comment: @Bruce: I tried to use an actionListener for xp:deleteSelectedDocuments but nothing is easier then just "reinvent" the action "Delete Selected Documents". Actually it's not that bad as it is still possible to keep code for deleting documents at a central place like SSJS function or Java class you'd call from action.